# LINQ to XML Select Nodes by duplicate child node attributes

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

Need to pull out the Employees who have a pager.

```
<Employees>
  <Employee>
    <Name>Michael</Name>    
    <Phone Type="Home">423-555-0124</Phone>
    <Phone Type="Work">800-555-0545</Phone>
    <Phone Type="Mobile">424-555-0546</Phone>
    <Phone Type="Cell">424-555-0547</Phone>
    <Phone Type="Pager">424-555-0548</Phone>
  </Employee>
 <Employee>
    <Name>Jannet</Name>    
    <Phone Type="Home">423-555-0091</Phone>
    <Phone Type="Work">800-555-0545</Phone>
  </Employee>
</Employees>
```

I've got LINQ to get all the Phone nodes that have a pager and I can get all the employees.  I can't wrap my head aroud drilling down to the phone node but still selecting the employee node?

```
var data = XElement.Load(@"employee.XML" );
var whoHasPager = from teamMember in data.Elements("Employee")
                where (string)teamMember.Element("Phone").Attribute("Type") == "Pager"
                select teamMember;
```

Comment: Where does the code you provided fail? What do you want the resulting data to look like?

Comment: He can get the node Phone, but can't refer anymore to the Employee, I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var whoHasPager = from teamMember in data.Elements("Employee")
                  where teamMember.Elements("Phone").Any(x => x.Attribute("Type").Value == "Pager")
                  select teamMember;
```

Comment: Yatzee! Thank you.  Now I can see how I can drill down /chain things together.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
var whoHasPager = from teamMember in data.Elements("Employee")
                where teamMember.Elements("Phone").Any(
                    p => p.Attribute("Type").Value == "Pager")
                select teamMember;
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `.Element` will return the first element and not all of them of type Phone.

Comment: aHa! Thats why '=="Home"' phone returned a node.

Answer (score 0):

You should see it as an SQL Statement maybe

```
SELECT employee from Employees where Phone Type='Pager'
```

therefore, the from statement should be Employees...
Note: I'm not really good in LINQ, but I think the idea is the same...

Answer (score 0):

You could try using an [XPath expression](http://www.w3schools.com/XPath/xpath_syntax.asp):

```
var data = XElement.Load(@"employee.XML" );
var whoHasPager =
    from teamMember in data.Elements("Employee")
    where teamMember.XPathSelectElement("Phone[@Type='Pager']") != null
    select teamMember;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var whoHasPager = doc.XPathSelectElements(
    "//Employee/Phone[@Type = 'Pager']/.."
);
```